# Fibonacci Sequence Ruby

Tags: ruby, sequence, fibonacci

I have coded the fibonacci sequence on Ruby:

```
n=40
def fibonacci (n)
    if n == 1
        1
    elsif n == 2
        1
    else
        fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
    end
end
puts "#{n}'s fibonacci value is #{fibonacci(n)}"
```

What code do I need to add to allow the user to select which part of the sequence they are looking for eg: n=35? I'm using the MAC terminal to test

Comment: Looks like homework, please show what have you tried so far.

Comment: SyOps, posting homework questions (if this is one) is perfectly OK, but SO has a rule that when doing so the asker is required to describe efforts (not necessarily code) he/she has made to answer the question.

Comment: Just write `fibonacci(35)`, which returns `9227465`. That's customarily written `fibonacci(35) #=> 9227465`. Hence, `n=35; puts "#{n}'s fibonacci value is #{fibonacci(n)}"` displays, `"fibonacci value is 922746"`.

Comment: [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) means a very specific thing and it's not a type of computer. It's just a "Mac".

Answer (score 1):

Ruby can take input from the user in a variety of forms, but the easiest is through `ARGV`, which encapsualtes the command-line arguments.

First let's clean up the implementation by using Ruby's flexible `case` statement:

```
def fibonacci(n)
  case (n)
  when 1,2
    1
  else
      fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
  end
end
```

Then feed input from the command-line argument thorugh to the function. Note that command-line input is always strings, so these need to be converted to integers with `.to_i`:

```
n = ARGV[0].to_i
puts "#{n}'s fibonacci value is #{fibonacci(n)}"
```

And then you call it like this:

```
ruby fib.rb 35
# => 35's fibonacci value is 9227465
```